# How to implement WSGI while using multiprocessing in flask?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, multiprocessing, wsgi

Suppose I have video process handler in a function, I want implement true parallel processing using `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading`.

So my code looks like this in general:

```
def start_subprocess(pid, progress_dict):
  '''
  Suppose this is video processing starter...
  '''
  from time import sleep
  # Simulating a subprocess with variable progress
  progress = 0
  while progress < 100:
    sleep(1)
    progress += 10
    progress_dict[pid] = progress


def get_current_progress_of_subprocess(pid, progress_dict):
  '''
  Suppose this is video current progress by pid, in this context current progress are all current frames has been processed... 
  '''
  # Retrieve current progress of a subprocess
  if pid in progress_dict:
    return progress_dict[pid]
  else:
    return None


def flask_service(progress_dict):
  from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
  from multiprocessing import Process
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/start_process')
  def start_process():
    pid = request.args.get('pid')
    if pid is not None:
      try:
        pid = int(pid)
      except ValueError:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Invalid pid.'}), 400

      # Start a new subprocess
      if pid not in progress_dict:
        process = Process(target=start_subprocess, args=(pid, progress_dict))
        process.start()
        progress_dict[pid] = 0
      else:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Process with pid {pid} already started.'}), 400

      return jsonify({'message': f'Process started with pid: {pid}'}), 200
    else:
      return jsonify({'message': 'No pid provided.'}), 400

  @app.route('/get_progress')
  def get_progress():
    pid = request.args.get('pid')
    if pid is not None:
      try:
        pid = int(pid)
      except ValueError:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Invalid pid.'}), 400

      # Retrieve current progress of the subprocess
      current_progress = get_current_progress_of_subprocess(pid, progress_dict)

      if current_progress is not None:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Current progress of pid: {pid} is {current_progress}.'}), 200
      else:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Process with pid {pid} not found.'}), 404
    else:
      return jsonify({'message': 'No pid provided.'}), 400

  app.run(debug=False, threaded=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
  with Manager() as manager:
    progress_dict = manager.dict()
    p1 = Process(target=flask_service, args=(progress_dict,))
    p1.start()
    try:
      p1.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      p1.terminate()
      p1.join()
    finally:
      print('Ending up!')
```

I have achieved what I want, but the problem is how do I deploy this with WSGI? As far As I know `from flask import Flask` class is creating instance of compatible WSGI. So what it looks like in deployment?

Also, am I actually implement true parallel processing? I just want make sure if I really do it. true parallel I mean is using hardware capabilities to solve parallel issue such as video processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is more complicated than it needs to be. You should create a function, `create_app`, which creates the Flask application and the `process_dict` managed dictionary and then returns the Flask application. Function`get_current_progress_of_subprocess` remains unchanged and I added handling of a KeyboardInterrupt in `start_subprocess`.

```py
def start_subprocess(pid, progress_dict):
  '''
  Suppose this is video processing starter...
  '''
  from time import sleep
  # Simulating a subprocess with variable progress
  try:
    progress = 0
    while progress < 100:
      sleep(1)
      progress += 10
      progress_dict[pid] = progress
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass


def get_current_progress_of_subprocess(pid, progress_dict):
  '''
  Suppose this is video current progress by pid, in this context current progress are all current frames has been processed...
  '''
  # Retrieve current progress of a subprocess
  if pid in progress_dict:
    return progress_dict[pid]
  else:
    return None


def create_app():
  from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
  from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

  app = Flask(__name__)

  # Create the managed dictionary:
  progress_dict = Manager().dict()

  @app.route('/start_process')
  def start_process():
    pid = request.args.get('pid')
    if pid is not None:
      try:
        pid = int(pid)
      except ValueError:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Invalid pid.'}), 400

      # Start a new subprocess
      if pid not in progress_dict:
        process = Process(target=start_subprocess, args=(pid, progress_dict))
        process.start()
        progress_dict[pid] = 0
      else:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Process with pid {pid} already started.'}), 400

      return jsonify({'message': f'Process started with pid: {pid}'}), 200
    else:
      return jsonify({'message': 'No pid provided.'}), 400

  @app.route('/get_progress')
  def get_progress():
    pid = request.args.get('pid')
    if pid is not None:
      try:
        pid = int(pid)
      except ValueError:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Invalid pid.'}), 400

      # Retrieve current progress of the subprocess
      current_progress = get_current_progress_of_subprocess(pid, progress_dict)

      if current_progress is not None:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Current progress of pid: {pid} is {current_progress}.'}), 200
      else:
        return jsonify({'message': f'Process with pid {pid} not found.'}), 404
    else:
      return jsonify({'message': 'No pid provided.'}), 400

  return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
  create_app().run(debug=False, threaded=True)
```